# Audit Commands run in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-cloud-dataproc

**Requirement**:
Be able to audit (using logs) all the commands run in Jupyter Notebook by a user. The Jupyter Notebook is installed on Dataproc.

Is there a way we can log the command run by the user at the same time.

I have already tried changing `Application.log_level` in jupyter config file to 0 but no luck.

Comment: Did you find a good solution?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there was some discussion about this FR in the Jupyter community: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jupyter/sLKCCBwlKEc. You would have to modify the Jupyter kernel to print out all commands to a file.